# Get color of an element using calabash-android

Tags: android, ruby, calabash

I have a text field(EditView) in my Android app, which changes color (borders) if it's value is not valid or empty. Also label(TextView) changes its color too in this case.

When I'm trying to get TextView using `query`, I see the following:

```
[0] {
                    "id" => "field_lable",
               "enabled" => true,
    "contentDescription" => nil,
                 "class" => "android.widget.TextView",
                  "text" => "Name",
                  "rect" => {
        "center_y" => 198.5,
        "center_x" => 51.0,
          "height" => 27,
               "y" => 185,
           "width" => 82,
               "x" => 10
    },
           "description" => "android.widget.TextView@a28btb00"
}
```

If i need to get text I can use `query("TextView id:'field_label'", :text)`

Is there any way in calabash to get the color of the TextView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible in Android.

In Android the `Views` (also the `TextView`) can have almost anything as a background not just a color (a bitmap, a shape, a gradient color, etc). Because of this there is no way to get the background color of a view (it is not stored).

This is not a limitation of Calabash but the Android system. You can get any property of an Android view if it is accessible.

You can query the following colors on the TextView (nothing is background):

- text color `:currentTextColor`
- hintTextColor `:hintTextColor`
- highlight color `:highlightColor`
- shadow color `:shadowColor`

Comment: Can I get some property, which will tell me at least something about color of the TextView?

Comment: Well, not the background. You can get the text color (:currentTextColor) the hintTextColor (:hintTextColor), the highlight color (:highlightColor), the shadow color (:shadowColor) - but not the background.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see updates. `:currentTextColor` worked for me. Many thanks.