# How to identify the text color and background in Calabash-Android

Tags: android, ruby, calabash, calabash-android

Is there any possible way to get the text color or background color of any particular text in Calabash-Android. I query in irb for same but doesn't get the required output. I think for IOS there is given methods to identify the color, but in Android it's limitation.

I have tried with text, id, index of particular text and apart form that I reached to github, forums pages but still scratching. does anybody got way in this scenario, if its kindly help.

Thanks in an advance
Vebhrocks

Comment: possible duplicate question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21185624/get-color-of-an-element-using-calabash-android

Answer (score 3):

`getTextColors` is a method available for any textview. It should be useful when the entire textview has the same colour.

`query("...", :getTextColors)`

To get the background colour you could do something like `query("...", :getBackground, :getColor)`

If you need to do advanced computations, consider making a backdoor method.

I do, however, think this might be outside the scope of a UI test. Consider using a different approach of testing this instead of using a UI test framework. A simple unit test might suffice.

Comment: I use this method but I didn't get anything regarding to the text. After every execution console was just returning me the "[]" brackets. not returning answers. have I Done anything wrong while querying? if it is then please kindly let me know.

below were the commands.

query("android.widget.TextView id:'my_id'", :currentTextColor)

query("TextView id:'my_id'", :currentTextColor)

query("android.widget.TextView text:'my text'", :currentTextColor)

query("TextView text:'my text'", :currentTextColor)